# Excel VBA: Overflow Error in when assigning similar data types

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I'm a beginner in VBA scripts and trying to create a macro that computes Tax components (Federal, State etc.) by taking the TaxableIncome and the name of the tax component as input. I'm filling the Tax brackets as a named range in "Data" worksheet. I declared a user defined data type TaxBracket to represent a tax bracket. As a first step, I want to read the data from the named Range in the "Data" worksheet into an array "taxBrackets" for further processing. Strangely it gives me an error when I'm trying to assign the values to the fields of the data type. Can someone tell me whats wrong here!!

[image]

```html
Type TaxBracket
  low As Single
  high As Single
  rate As Single
End Type

Function calculateTaxComponent(component As String, taxable_income As Variant) As Single

    Dim taxBrackets() As TaxBracket, overflow_income As Single, tax As Single
    Dim namedRange As Variant
        namedRange = Range("Data!US_FEDERAL_TAX_RATES").Value
        
    ReDim taxBrackets(1 To UBound(namedRange, 1))
    For i = LBound(taxBrackets) To UBound(taxBrackets)
        With taxBrackets(i)
            .low = CSng(namedRange(i, 1)) '<---- gives an Runtime(6) overflow error
            .high = CSng(namedRange(i, 2))
            .rate = CSng(namedRange(i, 3))
        End With
    Next i
    '.....................
    '.....................
    '.................
    calculateTaxComponent = tax
  End Function
```

Comment: Does the value you are trying to assign fall outside the bounds of a [Single Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/single-data-type)

Comment: No repro but from looking at your sheet are you using lakh notation? I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I'm debugging the function by using a test. In that, I'm passing the parameters like this. The values are well within the bounds. Sub test()
Dim tax As Single
tax = calculateTaxComponent("US_FEDERAL_TAX", 100000)
End Sub

Comment: Where is the parameter component used in the function. The function refers to a named range of 'US_FEDERAL_TAX_RATES' but your test is passing 'US_FEDERAL_TAX'.

Comment: For the time being I've hard-coded it, later I'd construct the name of the range using the parameter "component". But the issue I'm facing is where I'm assigning the value of the cell to array record (shown with arrow)